# How to post an unserialized array via wordpress rest API as meta data

Tags: rest-api

I am new to wordpress and am currently using WordPress Rest API to help automatically create custom posts using existing data. 1 of the fields needed is an array of image IDs so that images can be displayed. If a post is manually created on wordpress with the images, I know that the meta data would need to be in this format

```
"fave_property_images":["18339","18337","18321","17794","17793","17792","17791","17790","17789","17787"]
```

However, after posting through WordPress Rest API, the meta data automatically becomes serialized as such and no image is displayed.

```
"fave_property_images":["a:3:{i:0;s:5:\"18297\";i:1;s:5:\"18337\";i:2;s:5:\"17855\";}"]
```

Is there a way to prevent the auto serialization of my data?

**Edited** changed my getcallback function with reference from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/

functions.php

```
function add_fave_property_images() {
    register_rest_field('property',
        'fave_property_images',
        array(
            'get_callback' => 'get_post_meta_for_api',
            'update_callback' => 'rest_update_property_meta',
            'schema' => array(
                                'type'  => 'array',
                                'items' => array(
                                    'type'   => 'string',
                                    ),
                            ),
        )
    );
}

function get_post_meta_for_api( $object ) {
    //return the post meta
    return get_post_meta( $object['id'], 'fave_property_images', false) ;
}

function rest_update_property_meta($value, $post, $field_name) {

  // Update the field
  return update_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $value);
}
```

I have also tried `maybe_unserialize()` to no avail. I would appreciate any help thank you!

**2nd Edit**
I am currently using postman to post just for testing purposes. This is a sample json that I am sending

```
{
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "property",
  "title": {
    "raw": "test"
  },
  "content": {
    "raw": "<p>Singapore Management University (SMU) is the third autonomous university in Singapore. The university provides broad-based business programmes modelled after the Wharton School of the University of Pennsylvania. SMU was established on 29 July 2000 and is located in the Downtown area of Singapore. It has a city campus with a total enrolment of about 10,000 undergraduate and postgraduate students and comprises six schools offering undergraduate, graduate and PhD programmes in business administration, business analytics, financial services, accountancy, economics, information systems management, law and the social sciences. The university has over 30 research institutes and centres of excellence, and customised corporate training and lifelong learning for individuals are available through the university&#8217;s professional and executive development programmes. SMU is accredited by the AACSB International, EQUIS, and AMBA.</p>\n",
    "protected": False
  },
  "excerpt": {
    "raw": "<p>excerpt</p>\n",
    "protected": False
  },
  "author": 1,
  "featured_media": 18297,
  "parent": 0,
  "menu_order": 0,
  "template": "",
  "property_type": [
    1072,
    1073,
    1074,
    1071
  ],
  "property_status": [],
  "property_feature": [
    1079,
    1080,
    1081,
    1082
  ],
  "property_label": [],
  "property_country": [
    1065
  ],
  "property_city": [
    1357
  ],

  "fave_qs-ranking": "50-100",
  "fave_percentage-employed-after-graduation": "90%",
  "fave_school-fees": "$23000",
  "fave_local-to-international-students": "1:1",
  "fave_ielts-toefl": "10:10",
  "fave_times_ranking": "3",
  "fave_minimum-gpa": "23",
  "fave_property_images": ["18297","18337","17855"],
  "fave_property_price": "$200",
  "fave_property_map_address": "81 Victoria St, Singapore 188065",
  "fave_property_address": "81 Victoria St",
  "fave_property_zip": "188065"

}
```

**3rd edit** I have managed to display the array on `fave_property_images` field, however the field in `property_meta` remains a serialized array
And this is the resultant sample json from /wp-json/wp/v2/schools

```
{
  "id": 18397,
  "date": "2021-07-24T16:50:22",
  "date_gmt": "2021-07-24T08:50:22",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/school/test/"
  },
  "modified": "2021-07-24T16:50:22",
  "modified_gmt": "2021-07-24T08:50:22",
  "slug": "test",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "property",
  "link": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/school/test/",
  "title": {
    "rendered": "test"
  },
  "content": {
    "rendered": "<p>Singapore Management University (SMU) is the third autonomous university in Singapore. The university provides broad-based business programmes modelled after the Wharton School of the University of Pennsylvania. SMU was established on 29 July 2000 and is located in the Downtown area of Singapore. It has a city campus with a total enrolment of about 10,000 undergraduate and postgraduate students and comprises six schools offering undergraduate, graduate and PhD programmes in business administration, business analytics, financial services, accountancy, economics, information systems management, law and the social sciences. The university has over 30 research institutes and centres of excellence, and customised corporate training and lifelong learning for individuals are available through the university&#8217;s professional and executive development programmes. SMU is accredited by the AACSB International, EQUIS, and AMBA.</p>\n",
    "protected": false
  },
  "excerpt": {
    "rendered": "<p>excerpt</p>\n",
    "protected": false
  },
  "author": 1,
  "featured_media": 18297,
  "parent": 0,
  "menu_order": 0,
  "template": "",
  "property_type": [
    1072,
    1073,
    1074,
    1071
  ],
  "property_status": [],
  "property_feature": [
    1079,
    1080,
    1081,
    1082
  ],
  "property_label": [],
  "property_country": [
    1065
  ],
  "property_city": [
    1357
  ],
  "property_meta": {
            "_thumbnail_id": [
                "18397"
            ],
            "_wp_page_template": [
                ""
            ],
            "fave_property_images": [
                "a:3:{i:0;s:5:\"18297\";i:1;s:5:\"18337\";i:2;s:5:\"17855\";}"
            ],
            "fave_minimum-gpa": [
                "23"
            ],
            "fave_property_price": [
                "$200"
            ],
            "fave_property_map_address": [
                "81 Victoria St, Singapore 188065"
            ],
            "fave_property_address": [
                "81 Victoria St"
            ],
            "fave_property_zip": [
                "188065"
            ],
            "fave_qs-ranking": [
                "50-100"
            ],
            "fave_percentage-employed-after-graduation": [
                "90%"
            ],
            "fave_school-fees": [
                "$23000"
            ],
            "fave_local-to-international-students": [
                "1:1"
            ],
            "fave_ielts-toefl": [
                "10:10"
            ]
        },
        "fave_property_images": [
            "18297",
            "18337",
            "17855"
        ],
        "fave_minimum-gpa": "23",
        "fave_times-ranking": "",
        "fave_property_year": "",
        "fave_property_price": "$200",
        "fave_property_location": "",
        "fave_houzez_geolocation_lat": "",
        "houzez_geolocation_long": "",
        "fave_property_map_address": "81 Victoria St, Singapore 188065",
        "fave_property_address": "81 Victoria St",
        "fave_property_zip": "188065",
        "fave_qs-ranking": "50-100",
        "fave_percentage-employed-after-graduation": "90%",
        "fave_school-fees": "$23000",
        "fave_local-to-international-students": "1:1",
        "fave_ielts-toefl": "10:10",
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/schools/18397"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/schools"
      }
    ],
    "about": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/types/property"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
      }
    ],
    "version-history": [
      {
        "count": 0,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/schools/18397/revisions"
      }
    ],
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/media/18297"
      }
    ],
    "wp:attachment": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=18397"
      }
    ],
    "wp:term": [
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_type",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_type?post=18397"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_status",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_status?post=18397"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_feature",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_feature?post=18397"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_label",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_label?post=18397"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_country",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_country?post=18397"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_city",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_city?post=18397"
      }
    ],
    "curies": [
      {
        "name": "wp",
        "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
        "templated": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However if I add images by editing the post on wordpress, the json would be as follows and the field `fave_property_images` under `property_meta` would just be an array.

```
{
  "id": 18367,
  "date": "2021-07-23T11:13:46",
  "date_gmt": "2021-07-23T03:13:46",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/school/test-8/"
  },
  "modified": "2021-07-23T14:52:49",
  "modified_gmt": "2021-07-23T06:52:49",
  "slug": "test-8",
  "status": "publish",
  "type": "property",
  "link": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/school/test-8/",
  "title": {
    "rendered": "test"
  },
  "content": {
    "rendered": "<p>Singapore Management University (SMU) is the third autonomous university in Singapore. The university provides broad-based business programmes modelled after the Wharton School of the University of Pennsylvania. SMU was established on 29 July 2000 and is located in the Downtown area of Singapore. It has a city campus with a total enrolment of about 10,000 undergraduate and postgraduate students and comprises six schools offering undergraduate, graduate and PhD programmes in business administration, business analytics, financial services, accountancy, economics, information systems management, law and the social sciences. The university has over 30 research institutes and centres of excellence, and customised corporate training and lifelong learning for individuals are available through the university’s professional and executive development programmes. SMU is accredited by the AACSB International, EQUIS, and AMBA.</p>\n",
    "protected": false
  },
  "excerpt": {
    "rendered": "<p>excerpt</p>\n",
    "protected": false
  },
  "author": 1,
  "featured_media": 18297,
  "parent": 0,
  "menu_order": 0,
  "template": "",
  "property_type": [
    1072,
    1073,
    1074,
    1071
  ],
  "property_status": [],
  "property_feature": [
    1079,
    1080,
    1081,
    1082
  ],
  "property_label": [],
  "property_country": [
    1065
  ],
  "property_city": [
    1357
  ],
  "property_meta": {
    "_thumbnail_id": [
      "18297"
    ],
    "_wp_page_template": [
      ""
    ],
    "fave_percentage-employed-after-graduation": [
      "90%"
    ],
    "fave_school-fees": [
      "$23000"
    ],
    "fave_local-to-international-students": [
      "1:1"
    ],
    "fave_ielts-toefl": [
      "10:10"
    ],
    "fave_minimum-gpa": [
      "23"
    ],
    "fave_property_price": [
      "$200"
    ],
    "fave_property_map_address": [
      "81 Victoria St, Singapore 188065"
    ],
    "fave_property_address": [
      "81 Victoria St"
    ],
    "fave_property_zip": [
      "188065"
    ],
    "houzez_total_property_views": [
      "39"
    ],
    "houzez_views_by_date": [
      "a:2:{s:10:\"07-23-2021\";i:38;s:10:\"07-24-2021\";i:1;}"
    ],
    "houzez_recently_viewed": [
      "2021-07-24 12:15:46"
    ],
    "_edit_lock": [
      "1627030465:1"
    ],
    "_edit_last": [
      "1"
    ],
    "fave_property_location": [
      "1.2977432527616,103.84889449988,18"
    ],
    "houzez_geolocation_lat": [
      "1.2977432527616"
    ],
    "houzez_geolocation_long": [
      "103.84889449988"
    ],
    "fave_property_map_street_view": [
      "hide"
    ],
    "fave_agents": [
      "-1"
    ],
    "fave_property_agency": [
      "-1"
    ],
    "fave_single_top_area": [
      "global"
    ],
    "fave_single_content_area": [
      "global"
    ],
    "rs_page_bg_color": [
      ""
    ],
    "houzez_manual_expire": [
      "0"
    ],
    "_houzez_expiration_date_status": [
      "saved"
    ],
    "fave_property_map": [
      "1"
    ],
    "fave_property_images": [
      "18339",
      "18337",
      "18321",
      "17794",
      "17793",
      "17792",
      "17791",
      "17790",
      "17789",
      "17787"
    ]
  },
  "fave_qs-ranking": false,
  "fave_percentage-employed-after-graduation": false,
  "fave_school-fees": false,
  "fave_local-to-international-students": false,
  "fave_ielts-toefl": false,
  "fave_times_ranking": "",
  "fave_property_images": false,
  "fave_minimum-gpa": false,
  "fave_times-ranking": false,
  "fave_property_year": false,
  "fave_property_price": false,
  "fave_property_location": false,
  "fave_houzez_geolocation_lat": false,
  "houzez_geolocation_long": false,
  "fave_property_map_address": false,
  "fave_property_address": false,
  "fave_property_zip": false,
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/schools/18367"
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/schools"
      }
    ],
    "about": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/types/property"
      }
    ],
    "author": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
      }
    ],
    "version-history": [
      {
        "count": 0,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/schools/18367/revisions"
      }
    ],
    "wp:featuredmedia": [
      {
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/media/18297"
      }
    ],
    "wp:attachment": [
      {
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=18367"
      }
    ],
    "wp:term": [
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_type",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_type?post=18367"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_status",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_status?post=18367"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_feature",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_feature?post=18367"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_label",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_label?post=18367"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_country",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_country?post=18367"
      },
      {
        "taxonomy": "property_city",
        "embeddable": true,
        "href": "https://www.abroad.me/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/property_city?post=18367"
      }
    ],
    "curies": [
      {
        "name": "wp",
        "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
        "templated": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: how do you mean it becomes serialised? Where are you getting the serialised line of code from?

Comment: Is that your actual code? Because in your `get_post_meta_for_api()` function, both `$post` and `$field_name` are undefined. Also, the first parameter for the function is **not an object** and instead, it's an **array**. See the example [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/#read-and-write-an-extra-field-in-comment-responses).

Comment: I am getting the serialised line of code from my API end point /wp-json/wp/v2/schools

Comment: How did you post to the REST API - via JS, PHP, Postman, or? Can you edit your question and include the details including sample post data you posted? And how did you retrieve data from the REST API? Also, do your posts have multiple `fave_property_images` meta entries? If not, then you should call `get_post_meta()` with `true` being the third parameter.

Comment: I have updated the additional information above. I dont really know if my posts has multiple `fave_property_images`, my sample post json is above. But i can assure you i have tried both `true` and `false` parameters for `get_most_meta()` and they both didnt work.

Comment: The `fave_property_images` with the serialized value is not actually the custom REST field you added. Instead, it's a property in the `property_meta` field. So I don't know why that `"fave_property_images": false`, but what is the `property_meta` - is it added by a plugin or the active theme? BTW, please tag the user you're replying to so that they get notified of your replies - like this: @user209330

Comment: @Sally CJ I too am unsure what is the `property_meta`, I am currently using the houzez theme. I am guessing its the meta data for this custom post. However, all the other REST fields that I added has been reflected in the `property_meta`. And I hoped I have tagged you correctly as this is my first time on stackexchange

Comment: Yes, I did think it's the meta data for the post, but I was just wondering why those meta are being exposed like that. So I'd love to help you further, but you should contact the theme author/support and ask for their assistance regarding why your REST field isn't working when your code is actually now good. But you could also try deactivating plugins and see if your `fave_property_images` REST field is still `false` (when it shouldn't be so).

Comment: @Sally CJ alright I will try thank you for the help so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found my own answer, `fave_property_images` is not supposed to be an array, its just multiple strings. Therefore the following codes in function.php fixes the problem.

```
function add_fave_property_images() {
    register_rest_field('property',
        'fave_property_images',
        array(
            'get_callback' => 'get_property_images',
            'update_callback' => 'update_property_images',
        )
    );
}

function get_property_images( $object ) {
    //return the post meta
    return get_post_meta( $object['id'], 'fave_property_images', false);
}
function update_property_images($value, $post, $field_name) {
  // Update the field
    foreach($value as $ID){
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $field_name, $ID);
    }
    return;
  
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'add_fave_property_images');
```